# How should I include my custom logger using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, hapi.js

I wish to include my custom log in loggings,I am using pino module for loggings,
Here is the log example
This is the response every time when I am hitting my API

```
"1493118596934" "TRACE" "services-mc" "victoria-lap" "sr" "" "" "094ce63c-e067-4c4e-a441-92c247f0ed43" "" "GET" "/user/v1/favoritepets/?userId=123" "request received"
"1493118598480" "TRACE" "services-mc" "victoria-lap" "" "" "" "094ce63c-e067-4c4e-a441-92c247f0ed43" "" "GET" "/user/v1/favoritepets/?userId=123" ""
"1493118598490" "TRACE" "services-mc" "victoria-lap" "" "" "" "094ce63c-e067-4c4e-a441-92c247f0ed43" "" "GET" "/user/v1/favoritepets/?userId=123" ""
"1493118598494" "TRACE" "services-mc" "victoria-lap" "ss" "" "" "094ce63c-e067-4c4e-a441-92c247f0ed43" "200" "GET" "/users/v1/favoritepets/?userId=123" "response sent"
```

Here I have to include my custom log like this

```
"1493118596934" "TRACE" "services-mc" "victoria-lap" "sr" "" "" "094ce63c-e067-4c4e-a441-92c247f0ed43" "" "GET" "/user/v1/favoritepets/?userId=123" "request received"
*"pet_hit_journal" "15829507" "2017-03-10" "741184567" "" "web"*
"1493118598480" "TRACE" "services-mc" "victoria-lap" "" "" "" "094ce63c-e067-4c4e-a441-92c247f0ed43" "" "GET" "/user/v1/favoritepets/?userId=123" ""
"1493118598490" "TRACE" "services-mc" "victoria-lap" "" "" "" "094ce63c-e067-4c4e-a441-92c247f0ed43" "" "GET" "/user/v1/favoritepets/?userId=123" ""
"1493118598494" "TRACE" "services-mc" "victoria-lap" "ss" "" "" "094ce63c-e067-4c4e-a441-92c247f0ed43" "200" "GET" "/users/v1/favoritepets/?userId=123" "**response sent**"
```

Note:
The custom log messages for knowing that the data is fetched from the database when I am using the particular controller.
 Should it be possible? any idea, please...

Answer (score 1):

Logging in Hapi can be done through the [`server.log`](https://hapijs.com/api#serverlogtags-data-timestamp) and [`request.log`](https://hapijs.com/api#requestlogtags-data-timestamp) functions.

It's possible to intercept these manually and add any extra information you need using `server.on('log', ...)` and `server.on('request', ...)` before continuing to log your message. To keep your code organized, you can also wrap these in a [custom plugin](https://hapijs.com/tutorials/plugins). In one of these is likely where you would include your custom logger.

You should take a look at the [Logging Tutorial](https://hapijs.com/tutorials/logging?lang=en_US) as it explains the parameters for the above functions.

[Good](https://github.com/hapijs/good) is an official plugin to monitor and report on hapi server events. Also have a look at this. [Good-console](https://github.com/hapijs/good-console) will help you output those events to the console.