# In Node JS (Hapijs) how to globally access the Server variable

Tags: node.js, module, hapi.js

It must be simple but I can not find a good solution.

In a node module for example I want to log if something goes wrong. So I need want to use the Hapi function  server.log(...). An example:

In the server.js:

```
const server = new Hapi.Server({...});
server.connection({port:3000});
server.start((err) => {
  if (err) { throw err }
}
```

In the file test.js, I want to use the server variable created in the server.js. It should be usable in any module, because of logging and loading other plugins.

```
class Test {
  logInfo(text) {
    server.log(['info'], text);  // this will not work.
  }
}
module.exports = new Test();
```

I can ofcause add the server to every call for the module, but that would be an overkill.

How do I get a reference to the server variable outside the module it was created?

Comment: Typically in a hapi app, you're calling into other modules in response to requests in a handler. If you need to log you'd normally log in the handler/plugin. External modules that aren't plugins probably shouldn't know about your server or hapi's existence.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to log a message during a request, you can use [`request.log(...)`](https://hapijs.com/api#requestlogtags-data-timestamp).

Alternatively, you can use [`server.log(...)`](https://hapijs.com/api#serverlogtags-data-timestamp) by accessing the `server` object on the `request` object in a handler.

```
{
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/do/stuff',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        request.server.log('server.log() method');

        request.log('request.log() method');

        const test = new Test(request.server);

        test.logInfo('some text here');
    }
}
```

Check out my [answer on logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43626513/how-should-i-include-my-custom-logger-using-nodejs/43720340#43720340) in hapi, too.

In your case, you'd need to pass a reference to the server object to your module if you specifically wanted to log a message a hapi server event.

```
class Test {
    private server;

    constructor(server) {
        this.server = server;
    }

    logInfo(text) {
        this.server.log(['info'], text);  // this will work.
    }
}
```

But the commenter on your question is likely right. You should avoid this pattern if you want to avoid tight coupling of your modules.